Resolving KiCAD Power output and Bidirectional are connected
I am new to KiCAD and trying to use TPS63020 in my boost converter, but KiCAD is complaining about connecting power output and bidirectional PINs. I am not sure how to resolve this..
TPS63020 Datasheet link: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1809200040_Texas-Instruments-TPS63020DSJR_C15483.pdf

Should not be Vin an input PIN? Is that an error with the symbol I have downloaded?
This is the symbol I have downloaded from snapeda

==================== Update ==================
I have edited the symbol and I could get rid of some issues. Now this IC has got 2 VOUT PINS (P4 and P5) and they needs to be connected together. I have marked P4 as Bi-Directional and P5 as POWER OUTPUT. I can't do anything further with this. Please give me an idea to get rid of the warning below.


Power symbols such as PWR_FLAG are usually power inputs to prevent a DRC error for two power outputs being shorted.
Power output would be the pin on the IC. You can only tag one pin as output, as otherwise you'll get "power outputs shorted" DRC error.
Although, there's no definite way of using the power output checks that would work in all cases. Often there's a filter component or a fuse in between the output and input causing "No power output for the power input" issue.
You might want to change some of the pins not visible if you stack them.
